# How to create multiple Lines/Paths in perspective?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, perspective

I once saw in a video how someone created a set of paths which were alligend in perspective like this. Does anyone know how this can be done in best / quickest way?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great question! Here's how I would do it. First start with the shape you want to duplicate. In your case it is a curve:
[image: Curved Graphic]
Draw a line with no stroke and no fill from your shape to the desired vanishing point and group them together.
[image: Line with no fill or stroke]
Next use the Scale tool and place the Scale Anchor (the cyan cross-hair) at your vanishing point. While still in the scale tool, use **alt** and **shift** to duplicate the object to your first desired point.
[image]
After that just use Repeat Transformation (**Command+D**) to duplicate your object toward the vanishing-point!
[image]